# Change Order of Features in Popup with ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API version 4

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using version 4.5 of the ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API with a `MapImageLayer`.
I'm setting popup templates on each layer.

The problem is that, when showing the `Popup` following a click in the map, if there are multiple features found, I need to be able to order the features found.

Is there a way, like in the version 3 of the api, to order these features before they are displayed by the `Popup`?